# Adjusting size of custom view in Android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-layout, size, android-custom-view

I've built a custom view for speed display in Android. My goal is that the custom view's size shall always fit the parent element. Like this:

[image: how it's supposed to work]

I've already experimented with `onMeasure()`, but I couldn't figure out how to make it work.

Here's the code of my custom view:

```html
import android.content.Context
import android.graphics.*
import android.util.AttributeSet
import android.view.View
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat
import de.hdm.rollingchassis.R
import android.graphics.RectF
import android.view.View.MeasureSpec
import android.graphics.Typeface
import android.text.TextPaint
import android.util.Log


class SpeedView : View {

    constructor(context: Context?) : super(context)

    constructor(context: Context?, attrs: AttributeSet?) : super(context, attrs)

    constructor(context: Context?, attrs: AttributeSet?, defStyle: Int) : super(
        context,
        attrs,
        defStyle
    )

    // speed arc
    var speedDisplaySize = 300F
    var trackColor = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.white2)
    var progressColor = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.white)
    var trackBorderWidth = 5.0F
    var startAngle = 120F   //  90 degrees is the bottom of the circle
    var sweepAngle = 0F

    // speed font
    var speed = 0F
    var speedFontColor = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.white)
    var speedFont = "sans-serif-light"
    var speedFontSize = 90F

    // unit font
    var unitFont = "sans-serif"
    var unitFontSize = 25.0F


    override fun draw(canvas: Canvas?) {

        super.draw(canvas)
        canvas?.drawPath(path(300F), paint(trackColor))
        canvas?.drawPath(path(sweepAngle), paint(progressColor))
        canvas?.drawText(
            speed.toString(),
            (speedDisplaySize + trackBorderWidth) / 2,
            (speedDisplaySize + trackBorderWidth) / 2 + (speedFontSize / 4F),
            paintSpeed(speedFont, speedFontSize)
        )
        canvas?.drawText(
            "KM/H",
            (speedDisplaySize + trackBorderWidth) / 2,
            (speedDisplaySize + trackBorderWidth) / 2 + (speedFontSize / 4F) + 1.5F * unitFontSize,
            paintSpeed(unitFont, unitFontSize)
        )


    }

    private fun path(sweepAngle: Float): Path {

        val path = Path()

        var oval_start_x = trackBorderWidth / 2
        var oval_start_y = trackBorderWidth / 2
        var oval_end_x = oval_start_x + speedDisplaySize
        var oval_end_y = oval_start_y + speedDisplaySize

        val oval = RectF(oval_start_x, oval_start_y, oval_end_x, oval_end_y)
        path.addArc(oval, startAngle, sweepAngle)

        return path

    }

    private fun paint(color: Int): Paint {

        val paint = Paint()
        paint.color = color
        paint.strokeWidth = trackBorderWidth
        paint.style = Paint.Style.STROKE;

        return paint

    }

    private fun paintSpeed(font: String, fontSize: Float): Paint {

        val textPaint = TextPaint()
        textPaint.textSize = fontSize
        textPaint.textAlign = Paint.Align.CENTER
        textPaint.color = speedFontColor
        textPaint.typeface = Typeface.create(font, Typeface.NORMAL)

        return textPaint

    }

}
```

And this is the layout file:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_default="percent"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.3">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintHeight_default="percent"
            app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintWidth_default="percent"
            app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.5">

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:id="@+id/constraintLayout2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
                app:layout_constraintHeight_default="percent"
                app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.5"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0">

                <com.example.views.SpeedView
                    android:id="@+id/sv"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"

                    />

            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I'd like the speed custom view to fit the size of the ConstraintLayout with ID `constraintLayout2`. Does anyone know how to make that work?

Comment: It seems like you're using a fixed size for your custom View in `speedDisplaySize` which is probably constraining how big it all gets -- is there a particular reason why you're not using layout parameters instead?  Also, have you considered making this custom View through XML?

Comment: @IvanGarza Thanks for your respond! I've used a fixed size because I didn't know there was another option. I'm still a beginner in Android ;-)
How else could I do it? ```addArc()``` in the ```path()``` function is expecting an object of type ```RectF```. And ```RectF()```needs X and Y coordinates. Is there a possibility so set those coordinates other than as pixels?

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem might be related to the `speedDisplaySize` constant you're using to build your View hierarchy.

I would recommend that you take a slightly different approach and instead build your UI in XML surrounded by a `<merge></merge>` tags pair, just as you do with regular layout. E.g.,

```xml
<merge ...
    tools:parentTag="androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout">

   <!-- Build your layout in XML, where the 'parentTag' above specifies the root layout ViewGroup -->

</merge>
```

The `merge` tags will allow you to extend this XML View to a Java/Kotlin class of code extending the root `ViewGroup` that you want to specify. E.g.,

```
class YourCustomViewName @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context,
    attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
    defStyleAttr: Int = 0
) : ConstraintLayout(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) { // super class specifies the root ViewGroup type for the XML
   init {
      // Add any customizations, read in `attrs` or do what ever you want here
   }
}
```

This solution should save you a lot of code, and give a lot more freedom when modifying your custom View's appearance or behavior.

Last but not least, if you build your XML right, i.e. by making a lot of the sizes either `wrap_content`or `match_parent`, you should be able to arrive at a solution that gives you the desired solution where you can use the same custom View in a different sizes.